# ubuntu 14.04, Vostro 3559 Strange audio problem

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, dell-vostro

I have a strange Sound problem. After every boot up my Sound works fine until I plugged in the headphone. After I plugged in the headphone the Sound works for a shorter time and then gets stops working. I tried to reload the alsa but no use. Now the Sound is not working from both headphones and external speakers. Below is the list of playback devices.

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Answer (score 0):

Install pavucontrol (pulse audio volume control).

Run it . In the "output device" tab, try to  **manually** change "port" from speaker to headphone (or reverse) .

Comment: I tried with the pavucontrol. But now the audio is not working from both Headphone and speaker.

Comment: Look in the "configuration" if analog profile is selected.    Launch Alsamixer in a terminal to check faders state  when you insert jack   ( see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer   )  . Anyway, you could try  upgrade to 16.04...